# A strange sound always comes in the hotel

Tags: story, mystery

I had a sister who was very brave and and didn't fear ghosts or believe in them, and would try to find evidence on them.

One day she wanted to visit a hotel that was believed to be haunted to some extent. She stayed in a room of that hotel.

However, a strange sound saying "抬头,抬头,抬头...." would come. The language was not familiar to her, so she couldn't understand what it said. This continued for days, and she wasn't able to sleep well.

Finally, one day she decided to thoroughly search the hotel. She checked every room, looked inside all closets and cupboards, searched under tables, chairs etc., but couldn't find anything. The sound "抬头,抬头,抬头...."  was still coming, and it became louder, but seemingly started to fade away. She was tired and angry and tried to go to sleep, it seemed like the was nothing she could do.

The next morning, she woke up and thought about the incident. Surprisingly, the sound was not there anymore, not even once; it was a quiet morning. Finally, she realized what it was, and left the hotel at once (horrified, also convinced that ghosts are real).

What is so suspicious in this story?

I have added a hint for searching a complete anwer . By the way , the answers I have received till now already has the complete answer , but couldn't show it correctly :) . The answer also, is very simple to find !

> Hint 1 :- What is so special about the sound , even if it cannot be traced by searching every drawers , closets , and under tables , chairs etc. ?

Comment: There must be ghosts. What else could fill the gaps between words and "." or ","?

Comment: I am laughing at this comment XD . No no I have just separated the words by commas .The dots mean that it was continuing for a long time .

Comment: I made a huge edit to fix all the grammar, punctuation and vocabulary errors. Please roll it back if the edit ruined the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks @Bass , you made it better !

Comment: "She [...] and tried to go to sleep, it seemed like the was nothing she could do." and "The next morning, she woke up [...]" are contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This might not be it, and pretty sure it isn't but I guess that the suspicious part is:

> The characters of the sound ( 抬头 ) reassemble a person running away from something that appears to be a room.  抬 --> Hotel room , 头  --> Person running. Also "抬头" means "Look above", which is pretty dark.

> Probably she while investigating the hotel she reached the room where the ghost was (that why the sound was getting louder). When she thought about it in her room she came to the conclusion that ( 抬头 ) appears to have the meaning described above.  (I'm assuming she knows the symbol since she couldn't describe the sound unless she knew the language.)

> This might not be it, but I believe the answer is around the symbol 抬头.

Comment: have you tried the chinese traduction of those characters?

Comment: U are nearly at the right track .

Comment: Yes, I tried. @PierreSchneegans.

Comment: Will try to solve this @SouradipDas haha

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the suspicious part:

> If the "language was not familiar to her" as the story says, she'd have no way of knowing what the exact letters were just from the sound. Yet, the story is oddly specific about the letters and the language used, even though it would be more natural to describe the sound in English letters.

Of course, this assumes

> this story is presented exactly as narrated by the English-speaking sister (except in the third person). If that's not the case, there are several ways to explain this discrepancy: maybe she described the sounds to the narrator, who used their strong command of the Chinese language to transcribe those noises. Or perhaps the sister speaks fluent Chinese and represented the foreign-language ghostly incantations as closely as she could in Chinese; but the narrator, while translating her entire story from Chinese, decided to keep those sounds verbatim.

Comment: Your idea is interesting by the way , you are thinking it in terms of the letters and then the narrator .

Comment: Fine, assume the language wasn't familiar to her . But maybe she just heard the pronunciation of that word and the narrator has wrote this story .(or someone else who knows chinese. )

Answer (score 2):

> The narrator is the ghost

> The sister doesn't understand chinese, but the narrator does, so the narrator was here. He should be the ghost.

Comment: What if, the sister told the narrator how the word pronounced and the narrator wrote it correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

I have received many answers. Some were interesting and it would be wrong to classify them as incorrect, so all of the solutions of yours were correct and interesting.

However, @Rúben Maravilha correctly points out :-

> The meaning of "抬头" is "look above".

> Note that in the story the sister only searched everything inside the
>  hotel and those things definitely need not be above the hotel.
>  So the sister actually did not look above to search the hotel
>  thoroughly. Had she been looking above (at the ceiling or at the
>  roof), she would have understood what would have happened [or maybe
>  would do a handshake with the ghost :-) ].

Comment: Hello @Souradip Das. I edited your answer to hide the key part under the spoiler. Otherwise readers who want to solve it themselves may not be able to. Also I suggest that you wait a few days before giving your own answer. In my experience good answers still come after a few days

Comment: @DEEM it is not spoilered even after your edit

Comment: Edited it right now.

Comment: @SouradipDas I was thinking about that. I was trying to interpret those Chinese characters, from which I have to point out they are really interesting. They reassemble a person getting away  (  头  ) and (  抬  ) seems like "something holding a triangular object above a desk or a table" haha.

Answer (score 0):

She is the ghost. She was being told to look above for the light. The sound got louder as she got cloaer. When she realized she was not with the living it terrified her. She ran away. But since this is where she died she haunts the hotel and it replays over and over. Sometimes other people hear it. Hence the reputation for being haunted.

Her sibling was dead also and the the one calling to her. Not sure why he used the foreign language. Still working on that part.